# Why does my bash script work in a terminal, but not when using crontab?

Tags: bash, cron

Why does my bash script work in a terminal, but not when using crontab?

I run Pop OS (Debian/Ubuntu)

My crontab line:

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash root /home/henry/yupdate.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is my script yupdates.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade -y  
flatpak update -y
```

The script runs fine in a terminal.

The crontab is running in my /var/log/syslog

```
Jul 30 17:00:01 pop-os CRON[17989]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash root
/home/henry/yupdate.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: From which user is this cronjob?

Comment: The first argument to `/bin/bash` is the name of the script. Why do you have `root` there?

Comment: Don't redirect errors to `/dev/null` when you're debugging. Write them to a log file so you can see the reason why it's not working.

Comment: What you want to do is probably achieved by [unnattended-upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user name *precedes* the command to run in the system crontab. Use

```
0 * * * * root /bin/bash /home/henry/yupdate.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

instead.

Comment: The username field is not optional, its presence/absence depends on *which* crontab file the entry is stored in. It's required in the system-wide crontab file(s) (generally /etc/crontab and files in /etc/cron.d/), and cannot be used in per-user crontab files (generally someplace like /var/spool/cron/crontabs/) where the username is determined by the filename. BTW, if you use the `crontab` command to view/edit/whatever your crontab file, that's working with the current user's per-user file (even if the current user happens to be root).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read the documentation closely enough and confused the optional suffixes with the field itself.

Comment: The documentation is (IMO) not nearly as clear on this as it should be, but if you read carefully the [`man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) for the file format says (in the middle of a paragraph) "Each line has five time and date fields, *followed by a user name if this is the system crontab file*, followed by a command."

Comment: My Syslog now says:

`Aug  1 12:00:01 pop-os CRON[49786]: (root) CMD (root /bin/bash /home/henry/yupdate.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)`

I'll have to wait and see a day or so if the systems remains updated now.

Comment: Maybe just using crontab is easier than calling for a script

Comment: `0 * * * * root /usr/bin/flatpak update -q -y >> /var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log`

`10 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt update -q -y >> /var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log`

`20 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt upgrade -q -y >> /var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log`

`30 * * * * root /usr/bin/apt autoremove -q -y >> /var/log/apt/automaticupdates.log`